# Concatenate Jinja2 values in a request?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Imagine a list of `List = ["a", "b", "c"]`. Take the line:

```
{% for i in List %}
```

I need to create an input which has a `value` depending on `List.index(i)`. The desired output would be:

```
<input value="{{ request.form.List0 }}">
<input value="{{ request.form.List1 }}">
<input value="{{ request.form.List2 }}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it and am posting the solution for anyone that may need it in the future.

Treat the whole thing as a string: `{{ 'request.form.List0' + loop.index0|string }}`